# Poles and the Laurent series for $\frac{1}{z^4-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, singularity

In a problem, I have been asked to find the poles of the following function:

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{z^4-1}$$

Of course, $f(z) = \frac{1}{(z+1)(z-1)(z+i)(z-i)}$. So the singularities are $z=\pm1$ and $z=\pm i$.

In order to determine if they are poles (and not removable or essential singularities), we need to find the Laurent series of $f(z)$ and show that the principal part is finite. So how would we go about finding Laurent series, say centered around $z=1$?

Also, is there a way to determine that $z=\pm1$ and $z=\pm i$ are poles indeed, without finding the Laurent series?

Comment: Are you aware that $f$ has a pole at $z_0$ exactly if $\lim_{z \to z_0} |f(z)| = \infty$? it is also equivalent to $1/f$ having a removable singularity with value zero.

Comment: No, did not know that. I know what $|z|$ would mean, but  what does $|f(z)|$ mean? What would it be for the function in my case?

Comment: $f(z)$ is a complex, thus $|f(z)|$ is its module, exactly as $|z|$ is the module of $z$. Another way to see that these are poles is : if a singularity is removable, the function is bounded in its neighborhood, and if it's essential, the image of a neighborhood is dense  in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Try writing $f(z) = {A \over z-1} +  {B \over z+1} +  {C \over z-i} +  {D \over z+i} $. Alternatively, if you can write $f(z) = g(z) {1 \over z-p}$ where $g$ is analytic at $z=p$ then the Laurent expansion of $f$ around $p$ will look like $f(z) = {g(p) \over z-p} + g'(p) + \cdots$.

Comment: Let me see if I got that right. You know the meaning of $|z|$ for any complex number, but you don't know the meaning of $|f(z)|$, in spite of the fact that $f(z)$ is some complex number. Did I get that right?

Comment: A point c ∈ ℂ is a pole of f(z) if the limit as z → c of f(z) is ∞. So it is immediate from the fact that f(z) = 1/((z-1)(z+1)(z-i)(z+i)) that ±1, ±i are four poles of f(z). if c is a pole, then the *order of the pole at c* is the smallest k ≥ 1 such that the function (z-c)^k * f(z) has a removable singularity at c.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, yes it is kind of right. I know that $|z| = \sqrt{z \bar{z}}$. Similarly, we have $|f(z)| = \sqrt{f(z)\bar{f}(z)}$. What I am struggling with is finding the complex conjugate $\bar{f}(z)$ for a function. Also, in what sense do you mean that the function $f(z)$ is "just some complex number"? How can I treat the function like a complex number and find it's conjugate?

Comment: What I meant was that, for each complex number $z$, $f(z)$ is some complex number. And you know what the absolute value of that number is.

Answer (score -1):

To find the laurent series of a polynomial it is usually helpful to compute the partial fraction decomposition and rewriting the denominator as a limit of a geometric series usually leads to the desired laurent series. For example
\begin{align}\frac{1}{z^4-1} = \frac{1/4}{z-1} + \frac{-1/4}{z+1} + \frac{-1/2}{z^2-1}\end{align}
Consider $\frac{1}{z-1}$:
\begin{align}\frac{1}{z-1} = \frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{1-1/z} = \frac{1}{z}(\sum_{k=0}^\infty 1/z^k) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty 1/z^{k+1} \dots\end{align}

Comment: Great first answer! Hoping to see more input from you in the future :)

Comment: @KamalSaleh Thanks!

Comment: The question is about characterizing the singularities at the points $\pm 1$ and $\pm i$ via Laurent series. So you would need the Laurent series centered at those points, and not the Laurient series centered at $z=0$ (as you did).